# C# multiple forms open instead of one

Tags: c#, foreach, listbox

What I did was, I created a number of instances of different people and then added each person to a list called listOfPeople and I have each person's named in a listbox. Then I created a new form to print out the details of the person I select from the listbox, however when I select one person, all of their details open up in multiple forms. For example if I have Bill & Jill in the listOfPeople and I would like to view the details for Bill, 2 forms will open up, one showing the details for Bill and the other for Jill.

How can I fix this so only one form opens?

```
//This is where I create the instance to open the details form for a person
private void detailsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (peopleListBox.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No person selected!");
        }
        else 
        {                
            foreach (Person person in listOfPeople)
            {
                PersonDetails personDetails = new PersonDetails(person);
                personDetails.Show();
            }
         }
 }


   public partial class PersonDetails : Form
  {
    //This is the constructor that takes in the as a parameter and prints their data
    public PersonDetails(Person person)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        displayNameLabel.Text = person.PrintData().ToString();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the items in the ListBox are `Person`s, you just need to use the `SelectedItem` to create a single person. In your code above, the foreach loop explicitly creates and shows a form for each person in the list. I'm not quite sure why you are confused by that behavior.

```
private void detailsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (peopleListBox.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No person selected!");
    }
    else
    {
        PersonDetails personDetails = 
                        new PersonDetails(peopleListBox.SelectedItem);
        personDetails.Show();
    }
}
```

if the `SelectedItem` isn't a person, then you need a way to map the `SelectedItem` to a particular item in `listOfPeople`. For instance, if `SelectedItem` is a string representation of a name, and `listOfPeople` is a `Dictionary<string, Person>`, then you would do `PersonDetails personDetails = listOfPeople[peopleListBox.SelectedItem];`.

Comment: that does work because my constructor takes in a type of Person as a parameter to display their information.

Comment: Did you mean doesn't work? If so, then you need to specify what the values in the ListBox are and how they relate to the `Person`s stored in `listOfPeople`.